# To show $\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\ln x}{1-x}\right)^2dx = \frac{2 π^2}{3}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

Please help me, Wolfram alpha isn't showing steps to this integration, It's stuck in my head

Comment: Can you at least tell us what your first approach would be?

Comment: Consider the Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$, and what $\int_{0}^{1} x^n \log^2(x)\,dx$ is.

Comment: Sir, I expanded the natural log and it resulted in a series integral(1- (x-1)/2 + (x-1)^2 /3 -(x-1)^3/4 ...)^2 dx from 0 to infinity

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186003/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-the-improper-integral-int-0-infty-big-frac-ln).

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Define

$$I:=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x}{(1-x)^2}\:dx =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{(1-x)^2}\:dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^2x}{(1-x)^2}\:dx$$

The second integral transforms into the first one under the change of variable $u=1/x$. Therefore,
$$I = 2\cdot\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{(1-x)^2}\:dx $$
Now, for $|x|<1$, we have
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+\cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \:(n+1)x^n$$
Therefore,
$$I = 2\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty \:\left\{(n+1)\int_0^1 x^n\ln^2x\:dx\right\}$$
Note that for $b \geqslant 0$,
$$ J(b):=\int_0^1 x^b \:dx=\frac{1}{b+1} \implies J''(b)=\frac{2}{(b+1)^3}=\int_0^1x^b\ln^2x\:dx $$
It follows that
$$I = 2\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2}{(n+1)^2} = 4\cdot \zeta(2) = \boxed{\frac{2\pi^2}{3}}$$
as desired. The problem is solved.